# Google Chrome Bug - Web pages not displaying correctly

Tags: google-chrome, browser, html

Webpages are not displaying correctly in my google chrome browser. Text in the buttons are not 
displayed. Sometimes text appears garbled.

This is how facebook looks like, in my browser (google chrome.) - 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to clear your cache? If it works fine in another browser for you then you should probably re-install chrome. All is good on my end, so I don't think it's a problem with Facebook

Comment: Yes I cleared cache a million time also re-installed chrome, but nothing happened. No Problem with Firefox. Of course there is no problem with facebook, many other websites are also displaying with same glitch

Comment: That's weird if it just happened like that. Maybe try running Ccleaner or try installing a beta version of Chrome if you're already on the latest.